# Node.js, parse filename from URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I parse a url?

```
site.com:8080/someFile.txt?attr=100
```

or

```
site.com:8080/someFile.txt/?attr=100
```

I need to get `someFile.txt`, where is a file name I set by myself as the format (txt or some other).

*UPDATE*

I tried

```
var path = url.parse(req.url).path;
```

But I still cannot get the path (`someFile.txt`).

Comment: You should mention all the details from the beginning. - http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html

Comment: Do you mean you neeed to get `someFile.txt`?

Comment: Yes. It could be any file on server (i.e. `Kitty.jpg` or `order.json`).

Comment: Is the URL guaranteed to be in this format? Will there ever be a leading `http://`

Comment: No that isn't necessary.

Comment: Based on your edit, it does not have to be regex?

Comment: I'm not familiar with javascript regex (hence the comment instead of a reply) but in GNU regex it's simply '/\/\(.*\)[\/\?]/\1/'. Maybe you can easily translate it into javascipt regex, I don't know. Hope it helps, if only just a little.

Comment: @ShellFish RegEx isn't RegEx?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Something like this..

```
var url = require("url");
var path = require("path");
var parsed = url.parse("http://example.com:8080/test/someFile.txt/?attr=100");
console.log(path.basename(parsed.pathname));
```

Comment: I use node.js server. And I try to parse the code on server side.

Comment: i just did and it is `/test/someFile.txt/`

Comment: path.posix.basename will return the filename on windows and linux, path.basename only returns filename on windows https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_windows_vs_posix

Comment: This prints escaped characters, this should be: `console.log(decodeURIComponent(path.basename(parsed.pathname)));`

Comment: The signature '(urlString: string): UrlWithStringQuery' of 'parse' is deprecated.

Comment: @LiamPillay  this method is deprecated. use [new URL("url here")](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#new-urlinput-base)

Answer (score 9):

here's my working code, hope it helps

```js
import path from 'path'

const getBasenameFormUrl = (urlStr) => {
    const url = new URL(urlStr)
    return path.basename(url.pathname)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
decodeURIComponent(path.basename('http://localhost/node-v18.12.1-x64.msi'))

node-v18.12.1-x64.msi
```

Answer (score -1):

Your example can easily be dealt with using [Node.js’s `url` module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html):

```
var URL = require('url').parse('site.com:8080/someFile.txt?attr=100');
console.log(URL.pathname.replace(/(^\/|\/$)/g,'')); // "someFile.txt"
```

However, this doesn’t work with Node.js’s exemplary URL (’cause it’s got more path).

By truncanting the complete path starting at its rightmost slash, it’ll yield the file name:

```
var URL = require('url').parse('http://user:pass@host.com:8080/p/a/t/h?query=string#hash');
console.log(URL.pathname.substring(URL.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1)); // "h"
```

And if that idea is considered safe enough for the appliance, we can do it plain:

```
var file = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1).replace(/((\?|#).*)?$/,'');
                              /* hashes and query strings ----^  */
```